# Numerical integration plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to do a numerical integration plot in *Mathematica*. Specifically, I want to plot $r$ versus $\tau$ where, $$\frac{dr}{d\tau}=\sqrt{2F(r)}$$ $F$ being a quartic polynomial. The limit of $r$ is supposed to be from 0 to 1, and $\tau$ is supposed to extend from something like -3 to +3. I simply cannot figure out the logic to do this. But I must perform numerical integration because $F$ is not simple enough for the integral to be solvable analytically.
Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)?

Comment: Actually, this DE can be solved in terms of elliptic functions, but can reduce to elementary solutions if the quartic has multiple roots. Both the Jacobi and Weierstrass functions are built-in, so this is doable in principle. The question then is what your quartic looks like in general (all real roots, one pair of complex roots, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sense of the equation, when you have a differential equation of that type you can always put it in the form $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{2F\left(r\right)}}=\mathrm{d}\tau\rightarrow\int_{r_{0}}^{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}r'}{\sqrt{2F\left(r'\right)}}=\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau'$, so the idea is integrate until a certain point use the "cumulative integral" and make a list:

$list[1]=\{\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}r'}{\sqrt{2F\left(r'\right)}},\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_{1}}\mathrm{d}\tau\}$

$list[2]=\{\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}r'}{\sqrt{2F\left(r'\right)}},\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_{2}}\mathrm{d}\tau\}$,

$\hspace{3cm}\vdots$

$list[N]=\{\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{N}}\frac{\mathrm{d}r'}{\sqrt{2F\left(r'\right)}},\int_{\tau_0}^{\tau_{N}}\mathrm{d}\tau\}$,

So, for example, you want to get the integral for five values of $r$ $\rightarrow$ five values for $\tau$, thus:

```
F[r_] := 1/(2.0 * r^2)
tauVals = Table[i,{i,1,5}];
rVals  = Table[i,{i,0.2,1.0,0.2}]];
sols = NIntegrate[1/(Sqrt[2.0*F[r]]),{r,0,#} & /@ rVals;
```

Now what you want is a list plot of $\{f\left(r\right),\tau\}$, that will actally give you a quadratic funtion, in this case:

```
res = {{0,0},};
Do[res=Append[res,{tauVal[[i]],sols[[i]]}],{i,1,Length[tauVals]}];
ListPlot[res,AxesLabel -> {"tau","f(r)"}]
```

Now, if you do this with a very big number of points, you can actually interpolate the function (I only use five points as an example):

```
intFunc = Interpolate[res];
```

Now it's just a question of finding the solution to a series of points within the range and then making the plot:

```
rSols = r /. NSolve[intFunc[r] == #, r] & /@ tauVals;
Do[rSols[[i]] = Prepend[rSols[[i]], tauVals[[i]]], {i, 1,Length[tauVals]}];
```

With this interpolating functions you usually will get warings to use Reduce, but just ignore the warnings, unless you somehow run into a singularity when integrating. Plot to make sure you get a reasonable result:

```
Plot[Interpolation[rSols][x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

That is ofcourse something that looks like a square root function. I will generate the graphs later and place an update if it's the case.

Comment: Thank you. I will check and comment if it is working.